# tangent plane to a level set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, plane-geometry

I have the function $$f(x,y,z) = x^2 +y^2 -z^2$$ and I am asked to determine for each level set if I have a point that the tangent plane to the level set is parallel  to the plane $ z=0$ and another point that is perpendicular to $z=0$

I am not sure how I should handle this qeustion, what does $z=0$ meaning? I think that I need to find the normal vector of the plane $z=0$ and than check if it can be parallel or perpendicular to the gradient of $f(x,y,z)$ . is what I said is true? if yes how I should do it? and if no, I would like to get an explenation.

thank you kindly.

Comment: I am having trouble interpreting the phrase "if I have a point that the tangent plane to the level set is parallel to the plane z=0". Is there another way you could phrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to determine whether or not there exist points on the level set of $f$ such that their tangent planes are parallel (resp. perpendicular) to the plane determined by $z=0$.

Your idea is correct! The unit normal to the $z=0$ plane is $n=(0,0,1)$. So, you want to see if you can find solutions to the equations 
$$ \nabla f\cdot n=0$$
$$ \lVert \nabla f\cdot n\rVert=\lVert \nabla f\rVert.$$
The first equation describes exactly $\nabla f\perp n$, while the second equation is equivalent to $\nabla f$ and $n$ pointing in the same direction by $\lVert \nabla f\rVert =\lVert \nabla f\rVert \cdot \lVert n\rVert\cos \theta$, where we note $\lVert n\rVert=1$ and $\cos\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

Another tip: in this case, you should try to draw the level surface of $f(x,y,z)$. This will give you a guess as to what the answer should be in this case.

Comment: thank you for your answer,
but if I understand u correctly it will be the same point no matter the constant of the level set

Comment: I edited my comment if you can have a look plz

Comment: You should need to use the equation for the surface to determine the point. E.g. it should depend on the equation used for $f$ in the end, as an example using spheres tells us.

Answer (score 1):

z=0 means x-y plane so its normal vector is (0,0,1), and what you said is true.Just find that function's gradiant and check whether its perpendicular or parallel to (0,0,1).